# image loop works but the user controls partially work

Tags: javascript

Everything works except the back button it doesnt do anything whereas the forward button does but i have basically done the same code for both except making it decrement please no jquery and thanks for the help in advance also very new to javascript.

```
 var images = ['html.png', 'css3.png', 'WebDevLogo.jpg', 'Programmer%20Wallpaper.jpg', 'CSS3Thing.png', 'CSS3%20Wallpaper.jpg', 'HTML5%20Wallpaper.png'];
                var currentImage = 0;

                function loop() {
                    currentImage++;
                    if(currentImage > images.length -1){
                        currentImage = 0;
                    }
                        setImage();
                }

                function setImage() {
                    document.getElementById('image').src = images[currentImage];
                }

                function Forward() {
                    currentImage = currentImage++;
                    loop()
                }

                function Back() {
                    currentImage = --currentImage;
                    loop()
                }

                setInterval(loop, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back button doesn't do anything, because in `loop` you always move to next image. So `Back` goes back and then `loop` moves it forward where it was.

Move code rotating images from `loop` to `setImage`. Use `setImage` in `Forward` and `Back` instead of `loop`. By which I mean move

```
if (currentImage > images.length -1) {
    currentImage = 0;
}
```

---

Use increment and decrement without assigning it. It messes up your result.

```
++currentImage; // in Forward
--currentImage; // in Back
```

---

You could also improve your image rotation by using

```
currentImage %= images.length;
```

instead of

```
if (currentImage > images.length -1) {
    currentImage = 0;
}
```

---

Another issue, you may have, is that pushing `Back` or `Forward` doesn't restart `setTimeout` of `loop`. Use `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` for that or use shared time lock.

Comment: it all works now just had to add another if statement at the end.

            function Forward() {
                currentImage = currentImage++;
                loop()
            }

            function Back() {
                if(currentImage == 0) {
                    currentImage = images.length;
                }
                currentImage = --currentImage;
                setImage()
            }

            setInterval(loop, 3000);

Comment: useing the increment and decrement and everything works even with the setimage in the forward now guess it was that i had to use the increment thanks for all the help